# How to deploy git branch using Vercel REST API?

Tags: rest, curl, vercel

My Vercel (Next.js) project is connected to Github. How can I trigger deployment via Vercel rest API of a custom branch let's say `dev`?

The documentation is too poor for me to understand it: https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints#create-a-new-deployment